# How do I bind a javascript class to a asp:linkbutton

Tags: c#, javascript

I have a formview attached to a gridview so that when I click select on a record on my gridview, the record populates in the gridview. Now I want to open the formview in a lightbox, but I am running into trouble.

here is my javascript class:

```
    $('.lightbox').click(function () {
            $('.backdrop, .box').animate({ 'opacity': '.50' }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.box').animate({ 'opacity': '1.00' }, 300, 'linear');
            $('.backdrop, .box').css('display', 'block');
        });
```

here is my HTML:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("num") %>' CommandName="Select" runat="server" Text="Select" /> 
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

How to add the javascript class "lightbox" to the linkbutton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET controls have a `CssClass` property you can write to, which translates into a `class` HTML attribute.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" ... CssClass="lightbox" />
```

Comment: This works! But now the lightbox appears and closes immediately by the postback necessary to populate the formview. is there a way around the postback issue?

Comment: Keep in mind what a LinkButton is. Its purpose is to do a postback. You can kill the postback by adding a `return false;` to the end of your `click` handler, but doing that will stop the server code from executing. Lightboxes generally are accomplished using straight javascript, so you should probably look for a pure javascript solution, and make a manual AJAX call if necessary to retrieve the data needed for the lightbox.